# PostgreSQL IN matches any value in list - how do I match all values in list?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL IN can be used to match any value in a list. What if I need to match all values in a list? Is there a way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: How can a single value "*match all values in list*"? Can you show an example of what you are trying to do, please?

Comment: Sounds like you probably want a "relational division" query

Answer (score -2):

try `= ALL (subquery)` instead of `IN` (see [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ALL))